# React pass an object to the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this set up of my app in the ´app.js´ file I have my routers defined like this inside the render method

```
        <HashRouter>
            <StatusToast />
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    exact={true}
                    path="/"
                    render={props => (
                        <ImageScene{...props} title="Images & Information Search" />
                    )}
                />
                <Route path="/case/:id/images" component={DetailsScene} />
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
```

from `ImageScene` on a table row click, I call a method like this:
`this.props.history.push(/case/${id}/images)`

this trigger a route and load `DetailsScene` where I can get the passed in `id` like this `this.props.match.params.id` all works without any problem so far.

My question is how can I pass a more than a string (the id) can I pass somehow the whole object to the route?

I have tried to do something like this for 2nd route instead of:
`<Route path="/case/:id/images" component={DetailsScene} />`

to set up on the `ImageScene` a method which can expose the selceted object, for now lets just do a simple one like:

```
export function getSelectedRow() {
   return {
      title: 'test'
   }
}
```

and than set up the route like:

```
const object = getSelectedRow();

<Route path="/case/:id/images" 
       render={props => (<DetailsScene{...props} title={object.title} />
       )} 
/>
```

but I cannot make it work... any help would be graet, I'm totally new to react and the whole router.

Answer (score 0):

you could add state to history.push (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) which is available for component being rendered (DetailsScene). Remember to wrap DetailsScene withRouter(...) to have history.location.state available in its props.